# Drag and drop between different layouts

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a page with p:layout tags ( left & center ) . In the left layout i have a list of elements which are draggable.In the center layout i have a panel which is droppable.The problem is that the draggable elements only drag( move) inside the left layout.I don't know how to drag the element into the center layout. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are primefaces tags to support draggable and droppable as mentioned below

```
<p:draggable> and <p:droppable>
```

For example you can see the following prime faces example in the link [click here to see the example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/droppableBarca.jsf)